# why LegacyJsonLoader.js doesn't work? three.module.js:8390 Uncaught TypeError: this.set is not a function

Tags: javascript, three.js

I want to use LegracyJSONLoader.js but it throws an exception "three.module.js:8390 Uncaught TypeError: this.set is not a function"

I'm trying to use THREE.ObjectLoader(), but the loader throws an error:

```
THREE.ObjectLoader: You have to import LegacyJSONLoader in order load geometry data of type "Geometry".then I import LegacyJSONLoader but it doesn't work
```

I added

```
export default { LegacyJSONLoader };
```

at the end of "./example/jsm/loaders/deprecated/LegacyJSONLoader.js",
and added

```
import LegacyJSONLoader from '../examples/jsm/loaders/deprecated/LegacyJSONLoader.js;
export {LegacyJSONLoader,...};
```

at the end of "./build/three.module.js"

```
import * as THREE from "three";
...
  load(){
    let loader = new THREE.ObjectLoader();
    ...
  }
...
```

error occurred : 
three.module.js:8390 Uncaught TypeError: this.set is not a function

but in three.module.js:8390

```
function Color( r, g, b ) {
    if ( g === undefined && b === undefined ) {
        // r is THREE.Color, hex or string
        return this.set( r );
    }
    return this.setRGB( r, g, b );
}
Object.assign( Color.prototype, {
    isColor: true,
    r: 1, g: 1, b: 1,
    set: function ( value ) {
        if ( value && value.isColor ) {
            this.copy( value );
        } else if ( typeof value === 'number' ) {
            this.setHex( value );
        } else if ( typeof value === 'string' ) {
            this.setStyle( value );
        }
        return this;
    },
        ...
}
```

line 126 in LegacyJSONLoader.js

```
var _color = new Color();
```

why it cause the error : "this.set is not a function" ???

I also used webpack here is configs

```
let webpack = require("webpack");
let path = require("path");
module.exports = {
    entry: "./src/index.js",
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, "dist"),
        filename: "[name].bundle.js",
        // chunkFilename: "[name].chunk.js"
    },
    performance: {
        hints: false
    },
    mode: "development"
};
```

(I just started learning three.js and javascript a few days ago, and I am not very good at webpack...)

I hope to use THREE.ObjectLoader() successfully and know why LegacyJSONLoader() doesn't work

Btw, this is my first time asking questions on stackoverflow, I really hope to get answers. thx!

Comment: Can you share your code as a git repository? Or maybe as a live example? I've recently worked with `LegacyJSONLoader` for another issue without any problems.

Comment: I just find a good project at github ,but it doesn't update and support new three.js version any more. I want to fix it .https://github.com/va3c/viewer

Comment: I wanna modify this project to better understand three.js

Comment: @Mugen87 Im trying to use LegacyJSONLoader with latest release r117, and it has error  "parseMaterials is not a funciton". Do you have maybe example that works with this release?

Comment: No sorry. `LegacyJSONLoader` has been completely removed. The maximum version you can use with this loader is `r110`.